# How to print the current XML of a dynamically updated View

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

Say I have some views in an Android Studio app that I change via JAVA code.

Let's use a simple `TextView` as an example. It has it's XML code in its respective layout file.

But while code runs, I use its `.setText()` method to set a new text.

How do I print its new XML layout after the changes to see how it is formed?

This is very interesting for studying more complex elements and declaring them complete via XML instead of having to do lots of initialization via code.

---

Don't stick to the example given. The expected solution should show the entire XML for **any** `View`.

Comment: Why would setText change the XML? There is no XML being generated, really, the XML is a static resource and all the views are loaded by Java. I think it's just a one way street...

Comment: @cricket_007 I think he was asking about how to print the attributes of the `TextView` as you would see in an xml (e.g. layout_height, etc.,)

Comment: @gj_ - I really don't think so based on "How do I print its new XML layout after the changes to see how it is formed" and "very interesting for studying more complex elements"

Comment: It's the entire XML. I was thinking of a way to help me do mode XML codes and less java codes for things I know are pure interface and static. The example given is just not to worry about. I want a general answer for any View. ---- Precisely, but not limited to, I want to design a TabHost without doing java code, because it sounds just wrong coding the tabs (but that is another question).

Answer (score 3):

Android uses XML layouts to help you express your views without writing code, but there is no easy way to get back to XML.  You would have to write this yourself by writing code to crawl a view hierarchy, check every possible setting in every view, and outputting XML that would match those settings.  I suspect in some cases it might be very difficult or even impossible if a view doesn't have anaccessor methods for each property that you can set in XML.

In short, the general understanding is that inflating a view from a resource is the only time a dev needs to worry about XML.  In fact, the XML is not even really present in the APK (it's precompiled to another binary format.)

Comment: Sorry, mean to say XML is not even really present in the APK.  Will edit.